# regex strings separated by commas validating length of each string

Tags: regex, csv

I have a set of strings separated with commas,
like : cat,dog,Elephant

what to validate is like strings separated with commas should 
range from length of 3 to 6 . (strings can be anything like .&^*#$)

i.e a9&,bbbb,cc,ddddddd

in the above strings cc,ddddddd are invalid since dint come into 
the range of length 3 t0 6.

In this way a9&,bbbb,ccc,a12$%,adsdff

I went through many question that where posted in stack overflow
and got some ideas from it

^[1-9]\d([,][1-9]\d){0,3}$  this is a regex i got from stackoverflow posted question

this accepts digits alone but I need alphanumeric

I tired to change but dint work
^1-9a-zA-z{0,3}$

Could you please help me out?
and explain what does each symbol means so that i could learn more from
you people.

Thank you for posting answers for my previous questions too.

Comment: why don't you split on the commas, and iterate through the resulting array pulling out the ones that are good?

Comment: As written on the regex tag, when you ask of regex, always add the tag of the language you want the regex for.

Answer (score 1):

`[^,]` will accept everything BUT the comma that you are using as a separator. It isn't clear what your regex should give you, if the substrings that are not long 3-6, the substrings that ARE long 3-6, both mixed, both divided or what.

Try this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^(?:(?:([^,]{3,6})|(?:[^,]*))(?:,|$))*");
var matches = rx.Match("AA,BB&B,!CC,DDDDDD,EE");
foreach (Capture capture in matches.Groups[1].Captures) {
    string oneCapture = capture.Value;
}
```

The captures will be only the strings that are long 3-6.

Comment: it should accept only the substrings that are of length 3-6  i.e  if we enter: aaa,bbb,cc  it should be invalid, then if we enter aaa,bbb,ccccc,ddd it should accept.

Comment: Thank you very much could please guide me how to learn regex since it looks like greek and latin for me but I am trying hrad on it.

Comment: @Vignesh There are various tutorials on the net... But in the end I think it's a "try and retry" technique the only one that works :-) Be aware that there are many "dialects" of regex. The one of Javascript is different frome the one of .NET (that is different from the one used by the search-and-replace of Visual Studio).

Comment: @Vignesh http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an excellent resource for learning Regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is the following;

```
^([^,]{3,6},)*[^,]{3,6}$
```

To break this down the first ^ matches the beginning of a line the [^,]{3,6}, means 3 to 6 characters of anything but a comma followed by a single comma.  the ( )* enclosing that means repeat this 0 or more times then the last [^,]{3,6}$ part says end this with 3 to 6 characters which aren't a comma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried out but dint get the answer. From your description i could learn that the following regex ^[^,]{3-6}$ should accept aaa right? but its not accepting. could you please clarify me further.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick if the regex you mentioned already works fine for digits.
^.\d([,].\d){0,3}$

For reference I often use [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) reference, but it's kept a bit short to begin with, maybe someone else can provide a good tutorial.

There are some tools out there like [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) which help test and develop regexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following expression does what you want:

```
^(?:([^,]{3,6}),?)*$
```

The `[^,]{3,6}` part means "any character that is not a comma, 3 to 6 repetitions". That is the core of the expression. The parenthesis make a group, which will allow you to retrieve the values that were captured by that group.

The `,?` part means "a comma, zero or one times".

These parts are surrounded by a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`. That means that the contained expression is grouped, but you won't be able to retrieve the values that were captured by it. That group is necessary to apply a repetition charater `*`, which means "repeat the previous group zero or more times".

The anchors `^` and `$` mean "beginning of string" and "end of string". They prevent the expression from matching only part of a string. If you were searching for a pattern inside a larger string, you wouldn't want them.

You might want to try [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to learn more about regular expressions. The program has an analyzer that describes the various parts of the expression.